# Google Apps Scripting Web App Auto Refreshing Labels

Tags: web-applications, google-apps-script

I have a program using a Google Apps spreadsheet and it reads and writes data to the spreadsheet but I would like the gui to automatically refresh with data from the spreadsheet if things get changed in the spreadsheet.  I want to use this to create a page that is visible on one computer and then on another computer they click a button and it will increase the number from a different computer.  Is there a way to auto refresh web apps labels in the google apps scripting language?

```
 var dataByDepartment = {};
  var departments = [];

  var dataSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var dataSheet = dataSs.getSheets()[0]
  var data = getRowsData(dataSheet);

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("GNWDataGui"));

  app.getElementById('deathLabel').setText("gameDeaths: " + data[0].deaths);
  app.getElementById('killLabel').setText("gameKills: " + data[0].kills);

  return app;

}

function deathClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var sheet = dataSs.getSheetByName('General');

  data[0].deaths += 1;
  app.getElementById('deathLabel').setText("Death: " + data[0].deaths);
  setRowsData(sheet, data);

  app.close();
  return app;
}

function deathClickMinHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var sheet = dataSs.getSheetByName('General');

  data[0].deaths -= 1;
  app.getElementById('deathLabel').setText("Death: " + data[0].deaths);
  setRowsData(sheet, data);

  app.close();
  return app;
}


function autoRefreshHandler(e) {

       var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  app.getElementById('autoRefreshButton').setText("Auto Refresh");

  data = getRowsData(dataSheet);
  app.getElementById('deathLabel').setText("gameDeaths: " + data[0].deaths);
  app.getElementById('killLabel').setText("gameKills: " + data[0].kills);

  app.close();
  return app; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is undocumented feature:

UiApp.addTimer(handler, msecs);

don't forget to return UiApp instance and run timer again in handler.